# Why views are same when I run main.go again

Tags: web, go, browser-cache

main.go

```
package main
import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./templates/*"))

    func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "indexPage", nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/index", viewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

index.html

```
{{define "indexPage"}}
<html>
{{template "header"}}
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to TDT Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

another html file is header.html and is correct.

When I change the html and run main.go again, why the views are always the same?(I have cleaned the cache of browser)For example, change "Welcome" to "wwww", the browser does change at all.

Then I kill the progress of main.go and run it again, the view is changed.

Is there a better way to stop the main.go rather than kill this progress?

Comment: How do you serve your html? Static files or templates?

Comment: @inf I use templates

Comment: @inf I do not think this is related to the ways that serve the html. Because even I change the content of html, the view in browser doesn't change.(e.g. <h1>test1<h1>  to <h1>test2<h1>, in the browser is "test1")

Comment: Without any code it's hard to provide a definite answer, but it's extremely likely that you parse your templates only once on startup. This is good—parsing on every request is really slow—but explains why you don't see the updated template until an app restart. https://github.com/unrolled/render can help this with a flag to reload templates during development only.

Comment: @elithrar I have made it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering your templates only once as `templates` is a global variable.

To re-render your templates each time you can move the rendering to your function. This however is bad for performance as rendering is quite expensive but it's ok during development. As an alternative you can for example use what @elithrar proposed. A further alternative would be to use [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) and modify it to also scan for html files and not only go files.